# Calling get() on DocumentSnapshot in Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firestore, and I have some code like this:

```
let documentSnapshot = Firestore.firestore()
    .collection("my-collection")
    .document("my-doc")
    .getDocument()...
```

If I'm understanding correctly, I receive a DocumentSnapshot and this counts as 1 read as I get the whole document. So if I were to do, for example:

```
documentSnapshot.get("Title")
```

Does this count as another read as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DocumentSnapshot object contains the **entire** contents of the document in memory.  That means you can do whatever you want with it, and it will incur no more billing.  Accessing the individual fields is all done in memory.

Comment: Thank you for the help!